# Remove all occurrences of an integer from a list of floats

Tags: python, list, floating-point, element

I want to sort through lists of floats and take out all the values = 0, and keep the elements of the list as floats. Is this possible to do?

---

I have tried `a[:] = [x for x in a if x != 0]` but this gives me this error:

```
 a[:] = [x for x in a if x != 0]
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

So then I tried `a[:] = [x for x in range(len(a)) if x != 0]` but got a new error:

```
 a[:] = [x for x in range(len(a)) if x != 0]
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

---

What is another way to go about this? Order does not have to be conserved and I don't need the index of the elements I want removed.

Comment: Are you sure `a` is a list of floats?

Comment: yes, the list consists of                                     -9999.0,
-9999.0,
0.036885,
0.038996
-9999.0

Comment: That's not what your error message suggests. `print a` right before the list comprehension - what appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
blacklist = [0]
blacklist = set(blacklist)
myList = [e for e in myList if int(e) not in blacklist]
```

Better yet, make your blacklist a collection of `float`s:

```
blacklist = [0]
blacklist = set([float(i) for i in blacklist])
myList = [e for e in myList if int(e) not in blacklist]
```

Comment: Isn't that going to end up filtering out all float values in the range -1.0 to 1.0 (exclusive)?  `... if e not in blacklist` should be fine in both cases.

Answer (score 3):

you `a` object is a float, not a list

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,0,4]
>>> a=[x for x in a if x!=0]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just removing 0 from the list, then Bruce's answer is more concise.  However, if you want *all* non-floats removed from the list, you can do this:

```
>>> a = [1.2, 3, 4, 6, 0, 4.5, 3.2]
>>> a = [b for b in a if isinstance(b, float)]
>>> a
[1.2, 4.5, 3.2]
>>>
```